# Dúvida com trecho de código Java EL

Tags: java

Estou estudando um código e não estou entendendo esse trecho da EL:

```xml
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${not empty pedidoMesa}">
        Pedido: ${pedidoMesa.id} ${pedidoMesa.nomeCliente}  
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
       Mesa
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Esse como que foi referenciado esse `pedidoMesa`, para aparecer o `id` e o `nomeCliente`? Virei e revirei o código e não encontrei nada que possa relacionar com Model.

Comment: Blz Fernando, teria como detalhar sua dúvida? Porque o código acima é simples, o objeto pedidoMesa esta no scope (request, session, etc), e você pode referenciar via EL normalmente, o id e nomeCliente, devem ser acessíveis neste objeto.

Comment: Minha dúvida é a seguinte, não teria que referenciar o pedidoMesa ao Model Pedido por exemplo ? Não achei essa referencia. Como que o sistema sabe que esse pedidoMesa é referente a esse Model ?

Answer (score 3):

De forma resumida:

`<c:choose>` em linguagem de expressão é como se fosse um `switch/case` no seu código Java.

O `<when test="{condição}">` é como um `case "condição":`.

E o `<c:otherwise>` equivale ao `default` dentro de uma estrutura `switch/case`.

---

Repare que o *core* do JSTL não possui uma condição `<c:else>`, ou seja, se você precisa testar uma condição e a partir dela tomar uma ação pro caso de ser falsa, teria que fazer algo assim:

```xml
<c:if test="${not empty pedidoMesa}">
  Pedido: ${pedidoMesa.id} ${pedidoMesa.nomeCliente}  
</c:if>

<c:if test="${empty pedidoMesa}">
  Mesa
</c:if>
```

Não tem problema nenhum em escrever o código assim, porém alguns desenvolvedores preferem utilizar o `<c:choose>` (que é equivalente ao `switch/case`) e fazer uso do `<c:otherwise>` para tratar a condição contrária dentro de uma mesma estrutura. O código acima, poderia ser escrito assim:

```xml
<c:choose>
  <c:when teste="${not empty pedidoMesa}">
    Pedido: ${pedidoMesa.id} ${pedidoMesa.nomeCliente}  
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    Mesa
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Quando você utiliza `${pedidoMesa}`, será retornado o primeiro atributo com nome `pedidoMesa` que não seja nulo, não importa em que contexto da requisição ele foi criado/definido. Porém na seguinte ordem: `PageContext`, `HttpServletContext`, `HttpSession` e `ServletContext`.

Comment: Até aí tudo bem, mas não teria que referencia de alguma forma o pedidoMesa com o Model Mesa, pra chamar o pedidoMesa.id, por exemplo ? Essa referencia que não achei no código.

Comment: @Fernando resposta editada.

Comment: ok, agora entendi.Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Na verdade, tenho quase certeza que é traduzido para: `System.out.println("Pedido " + pedidoMesa.getId() + " " + pedidoMesa.getNomeCliente());`, mas de resto é isso mesmo.

Ele realmente não precisa associar a variável com a classe.

Comment: @Dudaskank Foi só um exemplo p/ mostrar que só estavam concatenando os atributos.

Comment: Então, mas se eu não preciso associar a variável com a classe, posso utilizar essa variável com qualquer classe Model do sistema ?

Comment: @Fernando desde que o objeto esteja no escopo da página, requisição, sessão ou servlet, pode sim. Editei a resposta **:)**