# Dúvida com Expression Language JSTL JSP

Tags: jsp, jstl

Como verificar o valor que está chegando na EL, na variável listPedidos de items ?

```
<c:forEach var="pedido" items="${listPedidos}" varStatus="id">

    <c:if test="${pedido.tipoPedido == 'MESA' }">
        <tr>
            <td>${id.count}</td>
            <td>${pedido.mesa.numero}</td>
            <td>${pedido.nomeCliente}</td>
            <td>${pedido.valorTotal}</td>
            <td> <fmt:formatDate type="time" value="${pedido.dtPost.time}" /> </td>
         </tr>
    </c:if>
```

Comment: Pode ser, só pra ver o que chega nessa variável.

Answer (score 0):

Não está claro.

Se quer saber o valor de `listPedidos` é só chamar um `${listPedidos}` em qualquer parte do documento.

Para entrar em loop somente se `listPedidos` não for nulo e nem vazio, pode-se usar o operador [`empty`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13712/reference.htm#WBAPP431) para testar a condição:

```xml
<c:if test="${empty listPedidos}">
  Nenhum Pedido.
</c:if>

<c:if test="${not empty listPedidos}">
   <c:forEach var="pedido" items="${listPedidos}" varStatus="id">

    <c:if test="${pedido.tipoPedido == 'MESA' }">
        <tr>
            <td>${id.count}</td>
            <td>${pedido.mesa.numero}</td>
            <td>${pedido.nomeCliente}</td>
            <td>${pedido.valorTotal}</td>
            <td> <fmt:formatDate type="time" value="${pedido.dtPost.time}" /> </td>
         </tr>
    </c:if>
</c:if>
```

Pode utilizar `!empty` ao invés de `not empty`, caso prefira.

Pode utilizar `<c:choose>` também, como [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/221983/4808).